# Python-how to calculate the highest tf-idf value of the first 100 words in different tweeets

Tags: python, twitter, scikit-learn, tf-idf, tweets

I have tens of thounds of tweets saved in one .txt file, I want to calculate calculate the highest tf-idf value of the first 100 words in these tweeets, in other words, I want to compare the word's tf-idf value between different tweets, presently,the only thing that I could complete is comparing word's tf-idf value in the same tweets, I cannot find a way to compare word's tf-idf value between different tweets.

Please help me,I have been upset for a long time because of this problem.
/(ㄒoㄒ)/~~

Blow is my code:(only able to calculate the term's tfidf value in same tweets)

```
with open('D:/Data/ows/ows_sample.txt','rb') as f:
    tweet=f.readlines()
lines = csv.reader((line.replace('\x00','') for line in tweet), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
wordterm=[]
for i in lines:
    i[1]= re.sub(r'http[s]?://(?:[a-z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]))+|(?:@[\w_]+)', "", i[1])
    tweets=re.split(r"\W+",i[1])
    tweets=[w.lower() for w in tweets if w!=""]
    stopwords = open("D:/Data/ows/stopwords.txt", "r").read().split()
    terms = [t for t in tweets if not t in stopwords]
    wordterm.append(terms)

word=[' '.join(t) for t in wordterm]
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df = 1,use_idf=True)
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(word)
terms_name = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
toarry=tfidf_matrix.todense()

#below code will output the tf-idf value of each tweets' terms.
for ii in range(0,len(toarry)):
    print u"第"+ ii +u"个tweets"
    for jj in range(0,len(terms_name)):
        print terms_name[jj],'-',tfidf_matrix[ii,jj]
```

Answer (score 2):

Now that I understand your question, I will try to answer your question a little better.

To get the top 100 'tf-idf' scores in a way that is comparable across all tweets would either mean that you are letting go of the notion that there are distinct tweets, or you want to be able to compare the same words to each other by tf-idf score.

So for the first scenario, imagine that all your words are in 1 'document'. This would essentially eliminate the 'idf' aspect of tf-idf, and what you'll get is basically a word count vectorizer, which can be compared with one another and you can get the top 100 words this way.

```
words = ['the cat sat on the mat cat cat']
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df = 1,use_idf=True)
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(words)
terms_name = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
toarry=tfidf_matrix.todense()

toarry:
    matrix([ .75,  0.25,  0.25,  0.25,  0.5])
```

The other scenario is that you take each tweet separately, and then you compare the scores by their tf-idf scores. This would result in the same words having different scores, because that's what tf-idf does - **it calculates the importance of the word in the document relative to the corpus**.

```
words = ['the cat sat on the mat cat', 'the fat rat sat on a mat', 'the bat and a rat sat on a mat']
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df = 1,use_idf=True)
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(words)
terms_name = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
toarry=tfidf_matrix.todense()
for i in tfidf_matrix.toarray():
    print zip(terms_name, i)

[(u'and', 0.0), (u'bat', 0.0), (u'cat', 0.78800079617844954), (u'fat', 0.0), (u'mat', 0.23270298212286766), (u'on', 0.23270298212286766), (u'rat', 0.0), (u'sat', 0.23270298212286766), (u'the', 0.46540596424573533)]
[(u'and', 0.0), (u'bat', 0.0), (u'cat', 0.0), (u'fat', 0.57989687146162439), (u'mat', 0.34249643393071422), (u'on', 0.34249643393071422), (u'rat', 0.44102651785124652), (u'sat', 0.34249643393071422), (u'the', 0.34249643393071422)]
[(u'and', 0.50165133177159349), (u'bat', 0.50165133177159349), (u'cat', 0.0), (u'fat', 0.0), (u'mat', 0.29628335772067432), (u'on', 0.29628335772067432), (u'rat', 0.38151876810273028), (u'sat', 0.29628335772067432), (u'the', 0.29628335772067432)]
```

As you can see in the results, the same words will have different scores in each document, because tf-idf is a score of that term within each document. So these are the two methods available to you, so depending on what you want, you can choose what's better for your purposes.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Ah, I thought it was 10. Well, better get posting some *actual* answers ;) (I flagged it for a mod anyway, so maybe they can convert it to a comment for you)

Comment: @JohnnyYeo  I have upload my code,please check it, thank you

Comment: @JohnnyYeo thanks first,but I don't think your answer can solve my problems. I have done this above,my question is how do I generate the top 100 words by tf-idf for all tweets,each words' tfidf value in each tweets is not my goal. How can I get that? thanks again :)

Comment: Hmm, I think this question would still help - is you collapse your matrix like I did in the last box, you'll have tfidf value for word in all tweets. you can use that to map the top 100 words, no?
So for my example, the top 2 would be {cat:3, the: 2}

Comment: @JohnnyYeo so, in your opinion, the way to calculate the tfidf value for words in all tweets  is summing  the word's tfidf value in each tweets firstly and then compare the summed value among every words? is there  a theory can support this method?

Comment: @qiangqin, see my edit on top. I think the tldr is that understanding what tf-idf really does is key.